# Looking for database insert example

Tags: database, 8

According to [`db_insert` manual page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!database.inc/function/db_insert/8) this function is deprecated and it is better to use Drupal 8 database connection to perform insert.

> Deprecated
>
> as of Drupal 8.0.x, will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. Instead, get a
>   database connection injected into your service from the container and
>   call insert() on it. For example, $injected_database->insert($table,
>   $options);

Now how can I get a database connection and call `insert()` method?

Comment: Do you mean outside of a class with injected services? Like `\Drupal::database()->insert(...);`?

Comment: No i mean inside class with injected services `class PetmdController extends ControllerBase`

Answer (score 22):

To inject the database service add/alter the following methods in your controller class:

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class PetmdController extends ControllerBase {

  protected $database;

  public function __construct(Connection $database) {
    $this->database = $database;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('database')
    );
  }

  public function foo() {
    $this->database->insert(...)->fields(...)->execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great for ControllerBase, but how would I inject the database service if my class was extending ContentEntityBase that is already passing different variables into the construct?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Berdir answer here is how you can inject your database service in your controller

```
$db = \Drupal::database();
$query = $db->select('location','loc');
$query->fields('loc', array('id', 'name', 'bond_goal','deposit_goal','date_created','date_updated'));
$query->addField('loc','name','location_title');
$table_sort = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')->orderByHeader($header);
$pager = $table_sort->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);
```

You can study `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Query` classes for more information

Answer (score 2):

First, as your quote says, it is deprecated for *Drupal 9*. Which means it will stay around for years and will not be removed from Drupal 8 ever.

But yes, its a good idea to avoid deprecated functions. Like any other deprecated function, you can always simply look at its implementation to see how the new way of doing it is. Although instead of calling out to \Drupal, you want to inject the database or whatever other service you need when that is possible (when you are in a service, controller, form, plugin, ...)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

```
$db = \Drupal::database();
$query = $db->select('k_product', 'p');
$query->fields('p', ['idpr', 'name', 'type']);
$data = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('idpr', 'name', 'type');
```

**Option 2**

```
$db = \Drupal::database();
$data = $db->query('SELECT idpr, name, code, detail FROM k_product')->fetchAllAssoc('idpr', 'name');
```